# .NET Code analysis Warning

Tags: c#, .net

What is wrong with the following code..The given code is not complaint with CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope  ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182289.aspx).. This code generate the following warning

**Warning   CA2000  In method 'CryptoComputer.Encrypt(string, string, string, string)', object 'new RijndaelManaged()' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new RijndaelManaged()' before all references to it are out of scope.**

```
 public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase, string saltValue, string initVector)
            {
                var initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
                var saltValueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltValue);
                var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
                string cipherText;
                PasswordDeriveBytes password = null;
                RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = null;
                MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
                try
                {
                    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                    password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations);
                    byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);

                    symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC };
                    var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);

                    var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                    var cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();


                    cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    password?.Dispose();
                    symmetricKey?.Dispose();
                    memoryStream?.Dispose();

                }

                return cipherText;
            }
```

How can I rewrite this code to satisfy the Microsoft guidelines

Comment: Use "using(...)" for password, symmetricKey, memoryStream.

Comment: Or- is it because that Microsoft's analysis rules do not recognize the syntax "password?.Dispose()"? What if you rewrite it as `if (obj != null) obj.Dispose();`?

Comment: Kennyzx is probably right... You will have to write the code the old way or suppress the spurious warning

Comment: Assuming your odd use of the nullable postfix is accepted by the compiler, it would be more tidy to create the objects outside the try block and get rid of the question marks. That would probably fix your issue. You should also have a separate try-finally for each disposable object.

Answer (score 1):

Every disposable object in "using(...)":

```
...
var initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
var saltValueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltValue);
var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
string cipherText;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (var password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations))
  {
    var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize/8);
    using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged {Mode = CipherMode.CBC})
    {
      var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
      var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
      cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
      cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
      var cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
      cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
    }
  }
}
return cipherText;
...
```

[using Statement (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it using a `Using { ... }` block like below, which will make sure that the disposable instance gets disposed of once it goes out of scope. make sure to wrap all disposable object in a `using {}` block and not just the one shown below.

```
using (symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC })
{
  //rest code goes here
}
```

Comment: @BinsonEldhose, have shown you the path. Like I mentioned you need to wrap all disposable object in a `using {}` block not just the one have mentioned in answer.